# Yii controller - how to load relation that might or might not exist?

Tags: php, yii

I have a `UserController` to handle user-related stuff. In my application, a user might belong to a group (being group another table/model) or might not (superusers don't belong to any group).

So, in the `actionUpdate` of `userController` I do this:

```
public function actionUpdate() {
    $model = $this->loadModel();
    $profile = $model->profile;
    $group = $model->group;
```

It works fine if the user belongs to a group, but when not, I get an error on view:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-1.1.14\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414
```

I understand that I get this error when trying to access a property of group, like `$group->name` and there is no group for that user. But I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: is the foreign key in your model is nullable?

Comment: @RafayZiaMir it is by default 0 (which means for me that the user has no group). Is it wrong? Should I force it to be null when user does not belong to a group?

Comment: Force it to be null, it is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check in the view if the user has a group?

```
<?php if(isset($model->group)) : ?>

   Do stuff that requires the use of the relation
   <?= $model->group->id ?><br>
   <?= $model->group->name ?><br>
   <?= $model->group->description ?>

<?php endif; >
```